# hide duplicates in a group except last row in .rdlc vs2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, rdlc

I am working in a .rdls vs2010 report. There is a group "Group1". I am using HideDuplicates for this group. HideDuplicates hide all but **first** row. But i would like to hide all but **last** row.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use HideDuplicates but the Hidden property of your textbox/row.

Something like this could work:

```
=IIf(RowNumber("Group1") = Count(Fields!OneOfYourFields.Value, "Group1"), False, True)
```